# pitcher meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Well,I know two meanings for pitcher,one used for a baseball player and one is a kind of container for liquids. But I don't get this one(Taken from the movie After Sex (2007)):
Man Number 1:

> Still trying to figure out if I liked it.(Sex)

Man Number 2:

> Wanna give it another shot?

Man Number 2 [Whispering]:

> Maybe you're a pitcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American baseball, a 'pitcher' is someone who throws the ball, and a 'catcher' receives it. In a sexual context, specifically among male gays, a pitcher is he who penetrates and a catcher is he who is penetrated. Often men prefer to be one or the other. Man Number 1 has just been penetrated by Man Number 2, and is not sure if he liked it, and Man Number 2 is suggesting he might prefer to be the penetrator. It is also possible to be a 'benchwarmer' (prepared to be either).

[How should we talk about sex? Ditch the baseball](https://rosehendricks.com/2015/03/26/how-should-we-talk-about-sex-ditch-the-baseball/)